# Save CheckedTextView checkboxes state

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I add my items to list using the following code. I need to save and load the state of the checkboxes, but I don't really know how.

I think I need to use `SharedPreferences`, which I try to do below, is
that correctly done?

But I also need to load the user selections when they open the app. I think I need to do something in `onResume()` but I can't figure out how to loop the checkboxes and check `SharedPreferences` for 
the state they should have.

Anyone have any suggestions to this?

```
    private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] pArray = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, pArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view;
            if (ctv.isChecked()) {
                pSelected.add(ctv.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("selection", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                settings.edit().putBoolean(ctv.getText().toString().toLowerCase(),true).commit();
            } else if (!ctv.isChecked()) {
                pSelected.remove(ctv.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("selection", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                settings.edit().putBoolean(ctv.getText().toString().toLowerCase(),false).commit();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I have a `CheckedTextView` defined in `list_item.xml` like this

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=""
android:gravity="center"
android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

Comment: What is mDrawerList? Is that Navigation drawer list are you talking about?

Comment: mDrawerList a Listview inside a navigation drawer.     private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

Comment: Anyone have any tips?